# .NET Core 3 & IIS Express maxAllowedContentLength not working

Tags: file-upload, .net-core, web-config, iis-express

I have a JavaScript application which is posting files to .NET Core 3 Web API.
Web API project works locally on IIS Express.

Files below 30 MB are working fine, but large files does not get through.

Here I tried;

1- Update `%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config` file with new `maxAllowedContentLength` value.

[image]

2- Add `RequestSizeLimit` attribute to Controller Action.

[image]

Is there anything else I am missing here?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem (since .NET Core 3), and found a workaround first, then a proper solution.

**Workaround:** in your web.config file, use "AspNetCoreModule" instead of "AspNetCoreModuleV2", but you no longer benefit from the advantages of the new module.

**A solution:** add this to your startup.cs file

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; // or your desired value
});
```

I found this info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-configuration. IIS options > In-process hosting model, then attribute "MaxRequestBodySize". For this to work, you still need to have your web.config configured with something like this:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" /> //or your desired value
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: did you use ci/cd ?

Answer (score 3):

For NetCore 3.1

1° you can add the attributes :

```
 [RequestSizeLimit(300000000)] // for 300Mb files

[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 300000000)]
```

2° in web config add the follow line:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
 <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="300000000"

</requestFiltering>

</security>
```