# Request Body Too Large - Kestrel - fails at context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am working on an ASP.Net core application where one of the actions is responsible to upload large files. The Limits.MaxRequestBodySize property is set to 100MB in the Startup.cs for Kestrel. The action that uploads the file is already decorated with [DisableRequestSizeLimit] and [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)].

Despite ignoring the limit at action level and setting the maximum body size to 100MB at global level, the request fails with 500: BadHttpRequestException "Request body too large" when the file I am trying to upload is only 34MB. The exception occurs in one of the middleware at "await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream)". And the exception stack trace also mentions the Content-length is 129MB. The exception does not occur if I set the Limits.MaxRequestBodySize to 200MB or to null.

Questions:

1. Why is the request size 129MB when I am uploading only 34MB file? what makes the remaining ~100MB?
2. When the request is already in context.Request.Body, why is it throwing error while copying it ("await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream)")to a new stream?

I really appreciate any help with these. Please let me know if anything is unclear, I can provide more details.

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution:

There was nothing wrong with the MaxRequestBodySize or maxAllowedContentLength. It was the size of the request that was causing the issue. Eventhough I was uploading file size of ~34MB, the file was converted to byte array and then to base64. This resulted in increased request size. I used IFormFile interface to send the file instead of byte array/base64, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that the default request limit in you application or the webserver is to low. Looks like the default `maxAllowedContentLength` is approx. 30MB.

Perhaps these link can help you out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840618/432074
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20369#issuecomment-607057822

Comment: Hi Orvar, thanks for your reply. The maxAllowedContentLength is set to 1GB and I have already tried the solutions these links are suggesting. Looks like MaxRequestBodySize is being checked every time the request body is read (context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync). Is there a way to ignore that check?

Comment: It´s super difficult to figure out when I don´t have/see all the code. Sorry :(

Comment: Hi Orvar, thank you very much for trying to help. I figured out the solution and posting here in this thread.